# Can anyone help identify what are the RF signals in this screenshot?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have Wifi on channel 1. Two Zigbee networks between WIFI Channel 1 & 2 (Zigbee channel13) and 10 & 11 (zigbee channel 22).

Capture was taken inside one of the two rooms. It is a data center that is not occupied yet. Rooms are empty. Corridors have LED lighting and camera.
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like channels 4, 5, and 8 are in use.

Answer (score 0):

The Wi-Fi network on channel 1 and the lower ZigBee network are visible. It looks like your second ZigBee network is actually on channel 23, not 22.

The rest of the noise just looks like Wi-Fi scans or Bluetooth frequency hopping or ZigBee scans to me.